# Error in R (mice package), too many weights

Tags: r, r-mice

I get the following error while imputing missing cases with the mice function from the library "mice"

```
 Error in nnet.default(X, Y, w, mask = mask, size = 0, skip = TRUE, softmax = TRUE,  :
too many (1104) weights
```

The problem is generated by the function `mice.impute.polr` and `mice.impute.polyreg` because of the default maximum number of weights.
I can not solved it by using the command `substitute` and neither by copying the functions' code and writing the new functions `mice.impute.polr` and `mice.impute.polyreg` (because of a function I cannot find call `augment`).
I've told that I should go to the source code to modify it.

How can I do it? Are there any other solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The neural net function called by `mice()` is stopping because the "maximum allowable number of weights" has been exceeded. The `MaxNWts` argument to [nnet](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/nnet/nnet) is there to prevent running code that will take a very long time to complete.

If you don't mind waiting then you can increase the `MaxNWts` parameter by passing it directly to `mice()`, which will be picked up by `nnet()`:

`mice(data = df_with_nas, MaxNWts = 2000)`

Answer (score 5):

Increase the MaxNWts in mice through nnet.MaxNWts argument

```
mice(data = df_with_nas, nnet.MaxNWts = 2000)
```

This is described in the documentation of the mice imputation functions, e.g. mice.impute.polr

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I found one factor variable has more than 10 levels. After I delete this var, the error is gone.